# Style sheet - not loading with web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm running a local copy of nodejs and have taken some code which runs a web service and references a local `index.html` on startup. This service is running locally on my desktop.

I've been playing about with CSS, and have found no matter what I do, the style sheet does not load, taking the configuration from the style sheet and dropping this within some `<style>` elements works fine. But for some reason or another, it's not reading the stylesheet.

Location of style sheet is: `c:\program files\nodejs\default.css`

HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
```

This is in the same location as `index.js`, `index.html`. Has permissions etc to read file.

Any ideas why this potentially may not be loading.

`index.js` code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res){    
    fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                    'Content-Length' : data.length
        });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: please format your code, is unreadable!

Answer (score 1):

Your server:

> ```
> http.createServer(function (req, res){
>    fs.readFile('index.html'
> ```

… is configured to ignore everything in the request and always return the contents of `index.html`.

So when the browser requests the stylesheet it is given `index.html`.

You need to pay attention to the path (which will be in the request) and serve up appropriate content (which for serving up static files means mapping it onto the file system, determining if the file exists or not, then loading that file or a 404 message), with the appropriate content type (so you'd need to determine that for each kind of file), and status code.

This is a significant chunk of work and not worth reinventing the wheel over so it would probably be best done by finding a static file serving module (Google turns up [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static)) for Node (or replacing Node with something like Lighttpd or Apache HTTPD).

If you want to serve up dynamic content as well as static content, then [Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a popular choice (and has [support for static files](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html)).